# Resolve DGET function "More than one match found" error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to match a list of range with certain criteria in a google spreadsheet. I am using DGET function for the same. Everything is working fine but the problem comes when there are many entries that contain the whole string and I receive "More than one match found in DGET evaluation.".

For the better understanding look below:

Sheet "Form Responses 1":

```
   B
-------
Ronald
Ronaldo
Ronaldinho
Rebarto
```

Matching sheet entries:

```
  A              
------           
Ronald           
Rebarto
Juhino
```

My Formula is:

```
=DGET('Form Responses 1'!B:H,"Date",{"Email Address","Logging In or Logging out ?","Date";A2,$B$1,$H$1})
```

Now the problem is Ronald is matching with "Ronald","Ronaldo" and "Ronaldinho" and I am receiving the error which says "multiple entries found".
How do we solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by Concatenating a constant variable before and after the name. For example `Ronaldo` becomes `mRonamdom` and `Ronald` becomes `mRonaldm`. This makes the Names Unique and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the data but to fix the formula so it doesn't get confused with similar entries in your database parameter you can add a character to the criteria field of the dget function as shown below (I'm using an '=' sign concatenated to the value I want to match with in the database parameter)

`=dget(database!$A$1:$B$11,$M$1,{"columnName";"="&F2})`

where
A1:B11 is my database
M1 is the matching column name
and `"="&F2` is the field with the caracter I chose that I want to match with to retrieve values from the matching database column, now even if the there are more than one matches found (becuase matching substrings"), the addition of the caracter contatenated with the matching value, should take care of the in-accurate error.